# Problem in finding an example regarding directional derivative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show by an example that continuity of f at any point is not sufficient for the existence of directional derivative at that point in all directions

Please help me in finding this example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Certainly you know this in one dimension?

Comment: What about \begin{equation}
x^{(2/3)}+y^{(2/3)}+z^{(2/3)} = a^{(2/3)} ?
\end{equation}